# Facing a Apple Store Connect Operation Error

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm new in IOS Development. I performed lots of R & D for solving this error. But Still No Luck.
I tried to upload my 2nd App version at Apple Store. I checked my asset folder. But In folder does not face any error and warning. All cleared. Does anyone Know When this error should come and How to resolve it?
[image]
Can Anyone Guide how to I can resolve this error?

Comment: It's pretty specific what the issue is. Your application icon is either transparent or of the wrong dimensions or both. **Solution:** Make sure it doesn't have a transparent background and matches the required dimensions.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thank you So much For your great response. this issue is resolved now. My App logo dimensions and it's not transparent. After, I tried putting a black background image behind the logo and trying. It's Worked. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good day.